# office addin dev 2016 and newer: how to add insert new page / slide button in the task pane app

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I am looking for directions (API reference / samples) 
to create a insert new page buttons along with 
Slide number grid view for quick navigation to slides in Powerpoint 2013 and newer additions with an addin

For this I guess we would need the Office JS Api to

```
i) Read the current number of slides, 
ii) Event listeners for add / remove slide 
iii) Insert / Duplicate particular slide into presentation 
iv) Navigate to particular slide
```

So, to begin with I started following - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/powerpoint-tutorial?view=office-js&tutorial-step=6

But, it only has specifications for navigating to particular elements and not the other features specified above, so are there any APIs with which we can -

```
i) Read the current number of slides, 
ii) Register event listeners for add / remove slide events
iii) Insert / Duplicate particular slide into presentation 
iv) Access menu items like Draw / Eraser
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no APIs in Office.js that support those scenarios. But these are good ideas. Please suggest them at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg You should address this to the questioner, not the answerer? Although he may, indeed, be interested in VBA if it can meet the four listed requirements...