# Office Add-In - Get number of slides in a PowerPoint

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, office365-apps

In the previous question [office addin dev 2016 and newer: how to add insert new page / slide button in the task pane app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52463252), it was questioned if it's possible to get the current number of slides of a PowerPoint file. I would like to know if someone has already solved this problem using the Office JS Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the linked question, this API is not currently available. Please suggest this at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).